# iOS - Asynchronous requests and UI interactions

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uicollectionview, alamofire

I have a page that uses Alamofire to retrieve images from Google Image Search API and display them inside a collectionView.  Everything works, but when the request is still loading I can't interact at all with the UI, whether it's clicking a button or scrolling the collectionView.  Is this normal behavior?  I would want the user to at least be able to press the Back button if the request is taking to long, or scroll up and down the collectionView while a new request is being processed.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, googleImageApiUrl, parameters: [:]).responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
    if let results = JSON as? NSDictionary {
        if let images = results["responseData"]!["results"] as? NSArray {
            for image in images {
                let url = NSURL(string: image["unescapedUrl"] as! String)!
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                    self.imageData.append(data)
                }
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To summarize, once the request is initiated, the user cannot interact with the page in any way until the collectionView has reloaded its data.  I figured if the request was asynchronous then I would still have the ability to interact with the UI.  Is this an Alamofire limitation, a general limitation, or am I doing something completely wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alamofire networks asynchronously. No worries there. The problem, though, is probably here:

```
let url = NSURL(string: image["unescapedUrl"] as! String)!
if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
```

If, as I suspect, that URL is a remote URL, then you are now repeatedly networking *synchronously*. `NSData(contentsOfURL:)` is *not* appropriate for fetching stuff across a network on the main thread. If you're going to reach out for more data on the network, use proper networking code - perhaps even using Alamofire some more...

Comment: So what would be the downside in fetching images with NSData on a global concurrent queue instead of the main queue?

Comment: Huh? You are _not_ fetching images on a global concurrent queue; that's the problem. You said it yourself: if the main queue is blocked, the user can't interact (and in fact the system will summarily kill your app dead).

Comment: Right, so I'm asking whether or not I can send those NSData requests to a different queue instead of the main one, so that the main one is not blocked.

Comment: Sure, that's what I'm saying. In fact at this point someone else has stolen my answer and turned it into actual code. Try that code!

Comment: So just to clarify - the actual Alamofire request is asynchronous, but when it returns, the stuff inside of it is executed serially on the main queue (unless, of course, I send it to a different queue manually).  Correct?  Yeh..that's correct haha.  It's all coming together for me now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

As I'm sure you now know, that interior `dispatch_async` to the main queue is redundant because you're already on the main thread. And, as others have pointed out, you definitely don't want to do `NSData(contentsOfURL:...)` inside this block, but rather request those images asynchronously, too. And as Matt points out (+1), you have Alamofire at your fingertips, so use that.

But there's a deeper problem here: You're loading the images up front! You shouldn't do that. Nor should you be loading them into an array. You should instead:

- **Lazy loading:** You should let each cell asynchronously request its own image only when the cell is needed, rather than trying to do this in advance. This means letting `cellForItemAtIndexPath` request the individual images for those cells rather than having `viewDidLoad` load them all.
- **Cache:** Rather than holding the images in an array (in which case you can easily run into memory problems), you should hold them in a `NSCache` or something like that. This way, if you have to purge them when you encounter memory pressure, you can safely do so, but keep the app running smoothly.

  Unless your images are both (a) very small; and (b) not numerous, you need a model backing your collection view that assumes that you might not be able to hold all of the images in memory at the same time.
- **Prioritize images for visible cells:** If a cell is reused, you should cancel the previous request for that cell. Otherwise, if you scroll quickly through the collection view, the requests for visible cells will get backlogged behind the requests for cells that have long since scrolled out of view. On slow network connection, this becomes a critical refinement.
- **Prevent timeouts:** Make sure you prevent requests from timing out. If you take care of the prior point, this issue is somewhat diminished, but on collection views in particular, it's still a real risk. You can either increase the timeout for your network requests or, perhaps better, wrap the requests in asynchronous `NSOperation` objects and then use `NSOperationQueue` to manage the requests with a `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of something reasonable like 4 or 5.
- **Preheating:** Earlier, I suggested lazy loading. Actually, if you want to get really fancy, you marry lazy loading of visible cells with a "preheating" (or prefetching or eager fetching) of cells that are near the visible cells so that they're ready when the user scrolls.

  This is a pretty complicated concept, so this is the last thing you should worry about at this point in time. But if you're interested in the concept, see WWDC 2014 video [Introducing the Photos Frameworks](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=511) for an example of what a sophisticated preheating mechanism might look like. (Note, I'm not suggesting you use the Photos.framework, but it's an example of what a clever fetching system does.)

Implicit in many of my observations above is that we need to optimize our apps for real-world scenarios. We do much of our testing with high-speed wifi connections, and sometimes forget that in the real world, users are dealing with spotty cellular connections. So, I would suggest run the app with the network link conditioner simulating a really weak cellular connection. Only when you do this will the importance of the above points about lazy loading, prioritizing the visible cells, and timeouts come into stark relief.

---

By the way, if you don't want to get lost in the weeds of some of these issues, you might consider using a `UIImageView` category designed for asynchronous image retrieval, such as [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage). It minimizes the amount of code you'll have to write.

Comment: a well deserved **slow clap**

Answer (score 1):

Try the approach bellow it may solve your problem, it works sending the request to a background queue with high priority, making it as fast as possible without lock the UI

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, googleImageApiUrl, parameters: [:]).responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0)) {
    if let results = JSON as? NSDictionary {
        if let images = results["responseData"]!["results"] as? NSArray {
            for image in images {
                let url = NSURL(string: image["unescapedUrl"] as! String)!
                if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                    self.imageData.append(data)
                }
            }

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```